# How to read .xlsx file in cshtml(razor with c#)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix

I need to read a excel(.xlsx) file in my website.
I already have implemented for .csv files(it was easy as it is comma delimiter file).
So can you just suggest the change so that I can implement it for excel file(.xlsx).
My code:

```
@{
var result = "";
Array userData = null;
char[] delimiterChar = {','};

var dataFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/data.csv");

if (File.Exists(dataFile)) {
    userData = File.ReadAllLines(dataFile);
    if (userData == null) {
        // Empty file.
        result = "The file is empty.";
    }
}
else {
    // File does not exist.
    result = "The file does not exist.";
}
}
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<title>Reading Data from a File</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <h1>Reading Data from a File</h1>
    @result
    @if (result == "") {
        <ol>
        @foreach (string dataLine in userData) {
        <li>
            User
            <ul>
            @foreach (string dataItem in dataLine.Split(delimiterChar)) {
                <li>@dataItem</li >
            }
            </ul>
        </li>
        }
        </ol>
    }
</div>
```

Comment: You don't do this in your view, but in a controller. Or rather, a separate class even. You use a library for this that can read Excel files. Library advice is off-topic for SO, but try searching the web for ".net excel library".

Comment: Okay thanks for your comment. Actually i am a beginner so, don't know about web development much.

Comment: @CodeCaster isn't entirely correct, as you **could** do it in the view (you did with the text/csv after all) but it does really belong in the controller, as indeed does the code for text/csv you currently have in the view. You would still need a library for reading the Excel, but you definitely also want to learn more about what sort of work belongs in models, in views and in controllers too.

Comment: @JonHanna Thanks, I did find a library called EPPlus which works well for .xlsx :).

Comment: Yes you can put loads of code in views, but that is a maintenance nightmare. Move it to your controller and libraries. FYI We use EPPlus in production for all our xlsx requirements. Good choice.

Comment: Why don't you read the excel file using OleDB then pass it to your view as a Model?

Comment: Also I recommend you to use LINQtoExcel

Comment: @CodeCaster  This looks more like ASP.NET Web Pages to me, not MVC, so there is no controller or model.And you can't do much in WebMatrix with MVC so I reckon the MVC tag is mis-applied in this case.